# EpiServer Web service 6.0, problems authenticating when using webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, episerver, episerver-6

I'm doing a console applications that will tell the EpiServer webservice to add a page. My problem is that I can't get the autentication to work. I've created a webservice user in Epi backofice. I can login to the webservice through the browser with my account.

A code sample from the console app is as follows.

```
var client2 = new ContentChannel.ContentChannelServiceSoapClient();
client2.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client2.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
client2.Open();

client2.ImportPage1(null, "Pagename", null, null, "sv", newGuid, parentGuid, "pagetype");
client2.Close();
```

The error message I get is

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException: The user does
>   not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right to access web
>   services on the remote site, for user     at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()
>   at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.ContentChannelService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()
>   at EPiServer.WebServices.ContentChannelService.ImportPage(String
>   channelId, String pageName, String[] propertyKeys, String[]
>   propertyValues, String cultureName, Guid pageId, Guid parentPageId,
>   String pageTypeName)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I don't know if I need to show how I've done in the config files but if I should add that, just tell me.
If anyone know how to go from here, please answer.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I get the error with a name, I get the login prompt, not the forms authentication, I can use some webservice-methods, such as

```
ContentChannel.GetMaxRequestLength()
```

but I get this error whenever I try to use the webservice properly or call the ValidateWebServiceAccess()

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException: The user does
not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right to access web
services on the remote site, for user andreas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, follow this link to setup and configure web service: http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/Web-Services/

Then go to EPIServer admin mode, click Config tab, then Permissions for Functions in Security subgroup, and click Edit near "Allow the user to act as a web service user". Add your user, click Save.

After that open IE, and open your local url `http://<yourlocalsite>/WebServices/ContentChannelService.asmx`

Ensure you are not redirected to Login screen, but receive browser login/pass popup. Try login with your webservice user.

Also ensure this is done in your code:

> When communicating with EPiServer CMS using a .NET soap client, set the property SoapHttpClientProtocol.PreAuthenticate to true to make sure that the username and password are sent to the server at every request

Comment: Hi! It's added so it's unfortunately not not problem.

Comment: Ok just to ensure - have you read this one, parts regarding locations and auth? http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/Web-Services/

Comment: That's the guide I followed.

Comment: What I see from reflector, you can receive such exception with empty user name only in case when user is not authenticated. Can you confirm that when you open your local url http://<yoursite>/WebServices/ContentChannelService.asmx in say IE you are not redirected to Login screen, but receive browser login/pass popup? Also, I don't see this in your code: `When communicating with EPiServer CMS using a .NET soap client, set the property SoapHttpClientProtocol.PreAuthenticate to true to make sure that the username and password are sent to the server at every request`